# How to center align the input descriptions and inputs for html perfectly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the descriptions and inputs in the middle of the screen. But I don't know how to align the descriptions and inputs both perfectly. Here is my html code and CSS.

```
       <div class="smallrow innerbody">
           <div class="col-12">
              <h1>Here is the side column</h1>
           </div>
           <div>
               <div class="col-6" style="text-align: right;">
                 <p>Please input your email address:</p>
                 <p>Please input your password :</p>
                 <p>gender :</p>
                 <p>city :</p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-6" style="text-align: left;">
                   <input type="email" name="email"><br>
                   <input type="password" name="password">
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

This part is relevent css code

```
.smallrow{
width: 98%;
margin: 10px;
position: relative;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}

col-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

My current work look like this
[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvYlB.png)

Comment: are you using bootstrap, right?

Comment: No, I am just trying to do some exercise about grid framework, I am a  beginner of front end developer.

Comment: cool... try the demo that I post here... see if this helps you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to float `col-6` to the left. You are also missing `.` before col-6 in your css.

Here is a fixed version of your code. https://jsfiddle.net/ttmtnq9c/

Comment: Your solution is so helpful.

Comment: My Pleasures :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can center them using the helper class `.text-center` and removing the `.col` class. I also put your text in a `label`, and wrapped each label in a `div` so that they're on their own row.

```css
.smallrow {
  width: 98%;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="smallrow innerbody">
  <div class="col-12">
    <h1>Here is the side column</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
      <div>
        <label>Please input your email address: <input type="email" name="email"></label>
      </div>
    <div>
      <label>Please input your password : <input type="password" name="password"></label>
    </div>
    <p>gender :</p>
    <p>city :</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ntbj1t1u/1/) that you can use...

Don't forget to add bootstrap:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
```